# Tabindex is not working in ie 7

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used a tabindex in my code, everything is going great its works finr in Firefox, ie8, safari but its not working properly in ie7, when i used a tab index in ie7 it come up to two input file then it get back to index one;

example:

```
<div tabindex=1>
    <a onclick="slide_down()" style="cursor:pointer;width:160px; padding-bottom:10px;" >sample link</a>
</div>
<div tabindex=2>
    <a onclick="slide_down()" style="cursor:pointer;width:160px; padding-bottom:10px;" >sample link1</a>
</div>
<div tabindex=3>
    <a onclick="slide_down()" style="cursor:pointer;width:160px; padding-bottom:10px;" >sample link2</a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I am facing same issue in IE11 as well. I have to press TAB key twice to advance to next value or navigate to the next field. Can anyone have a solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

As of IE5 any element can have a tabindex.  All current browsers now implement this behavior, and your original example will work fine in Opera, Firefox and Webkit.

But I don't know why your example doesn't work in IE7, because it should. Changing to a link is a pragmatic solution and will fix it, but shouldn't be necessary.

You might try programatically re-applying it using the camel-cased property name (which is required by older IE versions for most set-attribute values):

```
myDiv.setAttribute('tabIndex', '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Tabindex isn't allowed on a div tag. Try to put it in your link:

```
<div>
    <a tabindex="1" onclick="slide_down()" style="cursor:pointer;width:160px; padding-bottom:10px;" >sample link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use "tabIndex" with "I" capital letter not "tabindex"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `DOCTYPE`? Since tabindex is not supported in `DIV` tag, and IE7 compatibility layer may enable or disable the attribute based on `DOCTYPE`.

From HTML 4 specification:

> The following elements support the
>   tabindex attribute: A, AREA, BUTTON,
>   INPUT, OBJECT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/